# Sort objects by date/Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I would like to sort my data by date from newest down to oldest. I am getting Transaction objects from Firestore in the form of "2020-12-29". I have seen previous answers on how to sort arrays by date but I am unsure how I can sort it with my current object structure.

```
   func loadTransactions(){
    if let catId = self.categoryId{
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        db.collection("users").document(user).collection("Transactions")
            .whereField("catId", isEqualTo: catId)
            .getDocuments() {
                snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    self.budgetData.removeAll()
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let title = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let date = data["date"] as? String ?? ""
                        let amount = data["amount"] as? Double ?? 0
                        let id = data["transId"] as? String ?? ""
                        let absolute = abs(amount)
                        let trans = Transaction(transId: id, catId:catId,title: title, dateInfo: date, image: UIImage.grocIcon, amount: absolute)
                        self.budgetData.append(trans)
                       
   //                           let testArray = ["25 Jun, 2016", "30 Jun, 2016", "28 Jun, 2016",       //"2 Jul, 2016"]
  //                           var convertedArray: [Date] = []

  //                            var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  //                            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM, yyyy"// yyyy-MM-dd"

  //                           for dat in testArray {
  //                               let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat)
 //                               if let date = date {
  //                                   convertedArray.append(date)
 //                               }
 //                           }

 //                           var ready = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedDescending })
                        
                        var tranSet = Set<Transaction>()
                        self.budgetData = self.budgetData.filter { (transaction) -> Bool in

                           if !tranSet.contains(transaction){
                              tranSet.insert(transaction)
                              return true
                            
                            }
                            return false
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.setTotalAmountOfCats()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the data in your Firebase query using `order(by:)`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

In your example, it'll probably look like:

```
 db.collection("users").document(user).collection("Transactions")
 .whereField("catId", isEqualTo: catId)
 .order(by: "date")
```

If you implemented this, you could get rid of your `tranSet` and just append the Transactions in order (this is out of scope of the question, but I'd probably look at `compactMap` to transform `snapshot.documents` instead of appending them in order).

This assumes that your dates are in the format you listed (YYYY-MM-DD), which will alphabetize correctly, even though they aren't actually date/timestamp objects. If your data is in the format in your commented-out `testArray` section, than a different method would have to be used.